# What would the space under the image of this function look like?

Tags: differential-geometry

The function is as follows: $$\phi(x,y,z) = \left(\frac{yz}{x^2+y^2+z^2},\frac{zx}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)$$

And when $z=0$,the function becomes $ \; \phi(x,y,0)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$. Some properties of this function are that for any point $ \; p = (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3/(0) \; and \; \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \neq 0$; if $\; \lambda p=(\lambda x,\lambda y,\lambda z)$ then 
$$\begin{align}
\phi(\lambda p) & =\left(\frac{\lambda y \lambda z}{ \lambda^2 x^2 + \lambda^2 y^2 + \lambda z^2},
\frac{\lambda z \lambda z}{ \lambda^2 x^2 + \lambda^2 y^2 + \lambda z^2}\right)\\
& = \left(\frac{\lambda^2(yz)}{\lambda^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)},\frac{\lambda^2(zx)}{\lambda^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\right) \\
& = \phi(p)\end{align}$$ and so of course $\phi(-x,-y,-z)=\phi(x,y,z)$. I'm tempted to say this surface is going to look an awful lot like the projective plane and share certain features of it (like mapping 2 antipodal points into point under the image of $\phi$) but I can't exactly visualize it.

Comment: you realize that your function is not continuous near $z=0$ ? indeed when $xy\neq 0$ and $z \rightarrow 0$, $f(x,y,z) \rightarrow 0$, but $f(x,y,0)\neq 0$ if $xy \neq 0$.

Comment: so a priori you do not get a submanifold

Comment: Why surface? The image is inside $\mathbb{R}^2$, and you want to describe this image, right?

Comment: Glougloubarbaki, I do realize that. So lemme edit the domain rale quick.

Comment: Martin Brandenburg, I'm actually talking about the image of $\mathbb{R}^3/(0)$ under $\phi$ as a surface in $R^3$.

Comment: Where does the third component from?

Answer (score 1):

I claim that the image equals the closed ball $B$ with radius $1/2$ and center $(0,0)$.

For $\mathrm{im}(\phi) \subseteq B$, observe that

$$\left(\frac{yz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{zx}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)^2=\frac{z^2 (y^2+x^2)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2} \leq \frac{1}{4}$$

since for all $a,b,c \geq 0$ we have $(a+b+c)^2-4c(a+b)=(a+b-c)^2 \geq 0$.

I leave the other inclusion as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Use polar coordinates.

Let $(x,y,z) = r(\sin \phi \cos \theta, \sin \phi \sin \theta, \cos \phi)$, with $r \neq 0$, and let me rename your function to $f$.

Then $f(x,y,z) = \sin \phi \cos \phi (\sin \theta, \cos \theta) = \frac{1}{2} \sin (2 \phi) (\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$.

It follows that $f(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}) = \overline{B}(0,\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: Also, have a look at the graph of the function $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ over [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+xy%2F%28x^2%2By^2%29&lk=4) @ Wolfram Alpha. You can see that this surface intersects itself along the z-axis.

Comment: @MrX: I'm not sure what you are saying. I just used polar coordinates to represent a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: copper.hat: Your equation for f is polar coordinates where r=(1/2) can be written in the form $\rho(sin \theta, cos \theta)$ where $\rho = sin(2 \phi)$. If we take the image of the yz plane by considering all points where x=0 in the domain of f, the image under f is a figure 8 curve where $y=sin \theta$ and $z = sin(2 \phi)$.

Comment: @MrX: Sorry, I'm still having trouble following. Are you asking a question or making a statement?

Comment: I was making a statement about something I noticed when playing around with your formula last night. I apologize for not clarifying that. ;)

Comment: No problem at all, just wanted to make sure you weren't waiting from a response from me...